# Extrair informações do lattes

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, scrapy, rvest

## Introdução

Os pesquisadores brasileiros possuem, desde 1999, um site onde podem colocar informações sobre as sua carreira acadêmica. Estas informações são conhecidas como [Currículos Lattes](http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/busca.do). Eu desejo baixar alguns milhares deste currículos e escrever, junto com alguns colaboradores, um artigo a este respeito.

[Este link vai para o currículo da pesquisadora Suzana Carvalho Herculano Houzel](http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4727050Y3). Perceba que, ao clicar no link, o browser foi direcionado para uma página com um captcha. Este é o meu primeiro problema. Como passar por isso? Tentei duas abordagens diferentes: uma utilizando python, outra utilizando R.

## python

Aparentemente há um módulo de python bastante conhecido chamado [scriptLattes](http://scriptlattes.sourceforge.net/faq.html). Em teoria, ele seria capaz de baixar uma série de currículos lattes, desde lhe fosse fornecida uma lista de IDs de currículos (por exemplo, a ID do currículo que coloquei acima é 4706332670277273).

Entretanto, o módulo não recebe atualizações desde 2015. De lá pra cá, o lattes implementou o captcha em suas páginas. Creio que este seja um problema para o módulo, pois tentei rodar um dos exemplos em meu Ubuntu e recebi o seguinte resultado:

```
$ ./scriptLattes.py ./exemplo/teste-01.config
[ROTULO]  [Sem rotulo]

[LENDO REGISTRO LATTES: 1o. DA LISTA]
<urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
<urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Este comando só parou depois de eu cancelá-lo manualmente com Ctrl+C. Imagino que o problema seja, justamente, o captcha implementado depois da última versão deste módulo ter sido publicada.

Eu tenho alguma experiência com web scraping no python. Conheço os módulos `scrapy` e `beautifulsoup`, mas não sou um especialista neles.

## R

O R possui um pacote chamado [GetLattesData](https://github.com/msperlin/GetLattesData). Entretanto, a seguinte notícia está postada no seu repositório:

**ATTENTION: The package is not working as of 2017-11-26. The Lattes website, where the xml files were available, is offline. **

De fato, este servidor com os arquivos xml está fora do ar desde novembro do ano passado e nunca mais voltou. Testei o pacote hoje e ele continua não funcionando.

Encontrei outros pacotes do R que trabalham com o lattes, como o [CochoLattes](https://github.com/fcampelo/ChocoLattes), por exemplo. O problema é que preciso baixar os dados manualmente, entrando com os captchas um por um.

Tenho experiência com web scraping no R, trabalhando com o pacote `rvest`.

## Escavador

O site [Escavador](https://www.escavador.com/) faz, ele próprio, um scrap dos currículos lattes. Entrei em contato com a equipe do site e os dados não são disponibilizados. Entretanto, eles vendem acesso à API deles através de um sistema de créditos. Eu sou contra pagar para obter informação gratuita, mas caso nada mais funcione, talvez eu tenha que fazer isto mesmo.

## Conclusão

Vejam que meu problema nem é com a organização e a raspagem dos dados em si, mas é anterior a isto: como acessar as páginas com os currículos dos pesquisadores? Eu tenho experiência com raspagem de dados, mas nunca enfrentei um problema como este, com o captcha.

Além disso, não possuo uma lista com todos os IDs de todos os currículos que desejo. Cada currículo possui dois IDs únicos. [No caso deste currículo](http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4727050Y3), os IDs são 4706332670277273 e K4727050Y3, cada um acessado por uma url diferente:

- http://lattes.cnpq.br/4706332670277273
- http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4727050Y3

Embora os IDs sejam diferentes, as páginas acima possuem o mesmo conteúdo.

O que fazer neste caso? Creio que obter a lista de currículos que desejo não é difícil. [Este link](http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/busca.do?metodo=forwardPaginaResultados&registros=0;10&query=%28%20%2Bidx_nacionalidade%3Ae%29%20or%20%28%20%2Bidx_nacionalidade%3Ab%29&analise=cv&tipoOrdenacao=null&paginaOrigem=index.do&mostrarScore=false&mostrarBandeira=true&modoIndAdhoc=null) possui o endereço de mais de 5 milhões de currículos lattes. Eu poderia fazer um crawl e um scrap nele pra obter os IDs que preciso.

Portanto, o meu problema é baixar os dados de currículos (ou seja, páginas do tipo http://lattes.cnpq.br/4706332670277273) de forma automática, sem precisar entrar com os captcha. Como eu poderia fazer isto? R ou python, tanto faz pra mim.

Comment: Já leu sobre o [extrator de dados](http://memoria.cnpq.br/web/portal-lattes/extracoes-de-dados;jsessionid=6233596CE141DD077883032D31F5F172)?

Comment: Olá Marcus. O meu entendimento é que o Captcha *existe justamente* pra impedir isso que vc quer fazer (i.e. uma máquina fazer acessos automatizados). Sugiro ler [essa página no CNPq](http://lattes.cnpq.br/web/plataforma-lattes/extracao-de-dados/) e entrar em contato com eles solicitando o acesso. Pode evitar problemas (éticos ou até mesmo legais) pra você, e até talvez (ou provavelmente) permitir que você consiga fazer o que precisa de forma mais fácil. :)

Comment: Eu não conhecia esta página do CPNq sobre extração de dados. Como sou funcionário de uma instituição de ensino superior, vou dar uma olhada nos trâmites para pedir meu acesso a estes dados. Obrigado a vocês dois pela dica!

Comment: @LuizVieira acredito que seu comentário deveria ser uma resposta.

Comment: @hdiogenes Agradeço a observação, mas eu acho que o comentário não cabe como resposta porque ele não responde de fato ao que o AP quer (por mais equivocado que eu acredite que seja fazer o que ele quer). :)

Comment: Eu [quebrei o captcha do lattes](http://www.begnini.net/2016/02/08/quebrando-outro-captcha-com-opencv-e-python.html) a um tempo atrás. Acredito que não seja difícil integrar algum dos crawlers que você já tem.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver meu problema com ajuda da Superintendência de Informática da minha universidade. Eles possuem um convênio com o CNPq, que permite que tenham acesso a todos os dados que me interessam. Não é a solução que eu queria, pois vou depender de um intermediário sempre quiser atualizar os dados, mas é a solução que foi possível obter.

Comment: Já faz algum tempo que a plataformas Lattes não está mais utilizando captcha. Não sei se essa informação é relevante nesse momento, mas é só pra avisar caso alguém esteja lendo este post nos dias atuais.

Comment: Ao menos em janeiro de 2019, isso é verdade para as pesquisas feitas com o intuito de visualizar os currículos dos pesquisadores, mas o acesso aos xml destes currículos ainda precisam ser feitos preenchendo um captcha.

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço o sistema específico do Lates de captcha, mas vou tentar dar uma resposta "ampla" da solução.

Em geral o ideal é fazer um scraping só do HTML com `requests` e `BeautifulSoup` como você mencionou (ou, com minha nova biblioteca favorita pra isso, o [`requests-html`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html)). Esse método é preferível porque consome pouco poder de processamento e pouca banda, já que consiste só em requests do HTML e parsing, sem carregar imagens, scripts, etc.

Infelizmente o captcha é feito pra impedir esse tipo de scraping e é efetivo. A solução pra isso requer um pouco mais de tecnologia. O [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) é um *driver* de navegador; quer dizer, ele te disponibiliza um navegador "zumbi" e uma API pra controlar esse navegador programaticamente (clicar botão tal, ir para endereço tal, etc).

Ainda assim, ele não diretamente passa por captchas. A solução é saber onde estar o captcha, obter uma screenshot do navegador nessa área, e então ou usar um algoritmo de visão/OCR, se o captcha for fraco, ou usar um serviço de quebra de captcha (você envia a mensagem pra API do serviço e recebe de volta o texto contido).

Essas opções obviamente não são ideais; rodar um navegador consume bem mais recursos tanto da sua máquina quanto do servidor do Lates, por carregar imagens, CSS e scripts, e os serviços de quebra de captcha, apesar de baratos, não são gratuitos. Vale a pena analisar o site pra ver se existe algum jeito de contornar o captcha.